# Qt: control DockWidgets by QMainWindow::save/restoreState?

Tags: c++, qt

If I have a dock widget like this:

```
QDockWidget *shapesDockWidget = new QDockWidget(tr("Shapes"));
shapesDockWidget->setObjectName("shapesDockWidget");
shapesDockWidget->setWidget(treeWidget);
addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, shapesDockWidget);
```

following the documentation on QMainWindow::save/restoreState it seems that I could directly save/restore the dockwidgets by using function like:

```
void MainWindow::writeSettings()
{
    QSettings settings("Software Inc.", "Icon Editor");

    settings.beginGroup("mainWindow");
    settings.setValue("geometry", saveGeometry());
    settings.setValue("state", saveState());
    settings.endGroup();
}

void MainWindow::readSettings()
{
    QSettings settings("Software Inc.", "Icon Editor");

    settings.beginGroup("mainWindow");
    restoreGeometry(settings.value("geometry").toByteArray());
    restoreState(settings.value("state").toByteArray());
    settings.endGroup();
}
```

But how could I get the pointer to the restored dockwidgets? like the pointer shapesDockWidget ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting pointer of a widget has nothing to do with saving/restoring your GUI state. When you call `saveState()` function, it iterates over all components and stores their coordinates, orientation etc. When you call `restoreState()`, all widgets **should already be created** to let the function adjust their geometries.

If you need to get the pointer of your dock window, just store it as a member variable in your class. So define it as:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
[..]
private:
    QDockWidget *shapesDockWidget;
};
```

And use the variable when you create an instance of the dock window:

```
shapesDockWidget = new QDockWidget(tr("Shapes"));
```

Comment: So I have to first call shapesDockWidget = new QDockWidget(tr("Shapes")); before restoreState() if I want to restore my shapesDockWidget?

Comment: @Nyaruko, correct. Otherwise restoreState() will not find the widget to restore its state and will end up with a warning.

Comment: thanks so much, but how about this: when the saveState() is called no shapesDockWidget exist. Then I create it using shapesDockWidget = new QDockWidget(tr("Shapes"));, then I call restoreState(), will the shapesDockWidget be removed/deleted automatically?

Comment: @Nyaruko, no, restoreState() does not create/delete widgets - it just configures geometries of **existing** ones. In your case `saveState()` will not save state of dock widget because it does not exist. Calling restoreState() won't do anything with that dock window.